# The quests says to go to the ship. Except I'm *already* on the ship

Tags: saints-row-iv

In Saints Row IV, there are side-quests that involve you travelling back onto the ship (leaving the simulation) and talking to a specific character before doing any activity (back in the simulation).

However, the strange thing is that I'm on the ship, all the rules of the ship applies (no superpowers, etc.) yet still.. It doesn't detect I'm on the ship.
*I've noticed strangely is that there is a quest marker underneath the center console, which is inaccessible without no-clipping.*

I've tried going back into the simulation and re-exiting it (even at different portals), and nothing happens. The game still thinks I'm "in" the simulation, and not on the ship.

---

Anyways, here's a screenshot:
[Defintely on the ship. http://cloud-4.steamusercontent.com/ugc/39738595549738561/294A21EAEB4EE8D299154724C9327925722593D4/](http://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=375906221)

---

#### Is there any way to trigger the action completion WITHOUT clipping?

Or, if there is no way to do it without clipping, how do I clip then? Or are there any alternate methods?

Comment: ...could it be possible the location is actually on the lower tier of the ship? I don't remember precisely.

Comment: I'm so dumb enough to not consider that the ship has two levels...Ish. **You're totally correct.**

Comment: @aytimothy there will be a view time where the "quest" tells you Return to the ship and you have to search around the shipp with wich NPC you have to talk... (happend also to me)

Comment: Oh, might I add: Sometimes, the trigger point is actually right next to  the console. (Right next to the point where you exit the simulation from; the chair thingy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually supposed to go to the lower deck of the ship!

There you will find your next quest! (See also: My comment.)

Comment: Completely forgot to mark as correct.. And the tick button isn't working for me. (I'll try again later)